How to secure assets in vite rails?
I would like to secure some important assets in rails. How can I do that?
I'm using vite to transpile typescript, vue components, etc. And vite_rails gem to integrate it with rails.
The problem is that vite_rails outputs assets into public folder, but I don't want them to be public. Only authorised users should be able to use these assets.

Looks like there are configuration options for controlling where vite outputs assets. https://vite-ruby.netlify.app/config/#publicdir
